# How to implement the symplectic transformation in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

Consider a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$, which can be diagonalized by a *symplectic matrix* S such that

$$A = SA_d S^T$$

where $A_d = \oplus_{k=1}^{2} a_k \mathbf{I}$ where $a_k$ is the $k$-th [symplectic eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix). And $S$ is a 4-dimensional matrix satisfying $S\Omega S^T = \Omega$, with $\Omega = [0, \mathbf{I}_{2\times 2}; -\mathbf{I}_{2\times 2},0]$.

My question: How can one find the matrix $S$, given $A$ using *Mathematica*?  It would help to illustrate with an example.

Comment: I have no answer but will just add two related questions from other sites: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1751934/245806 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171842/245806

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, it does not help much. One of the questions is not answered, and another has got a partial answer. I think Symplectic transformation is a crucial concept and there must be a way to implement it in Mathematica. Unfortunately, I do not have a sound grip on coding.

Comment: Of course you are right. Basically if you have any way of expressing the decomposition in terms of others that are already built in such as eigenvalue, singular value, Jordan, Schur, Hessenberg, QR, Cholesky, or LU the answer should be straightforward. Do you happen to have any additional information at all about such approaches? I was able to implement the Bloch-Messiah/Euler decomposition of a symplectic matrix in Mathematica by relating it back to eigendecomposition myself.

Comment: Zubin, can you, please, give an example matrix (in copy-and-paste-able wolfram language in a code block)? This will help ease the burden on those who may potentially offer solutions. Thanks!